# How to make a div's height change to accommodate other div's contained in it?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a main div "content." In it is another div "projectlist" and in THAT are several thumbnail-sized div's that I'm using as image sprites to link to other pages. However, the "content" div doesn't seem to want to make it's height bigger when I add a lot of the thumbnail div's.

Here is a test page for you to see what I'm working with: http://willryan.us/test/content/design.html

If you hover over the first couple thumbnails, you'll see the blue overlay (only a few have the hover so far and it's just a duplicate). I'm trying to get this on all thumbnails via image sprites. So I've wrapped each image with a div to do so.

But the "content" div isn't getting bigger once it hits four rows of thumbnails. If you go to the photo page, you can see the content div behaving correctly (getting taller when there's more images in it).

I'm assuming the problem lies in the smaller div's on the design page since I'm not using div's for the thumbnails on the photo page.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set overflow:auto on #content and that should sort it out.

Comment: Oh man I feel stupid... thanks guys, both of those codes fixes it. However, now the thumbnails butt right up against the bottom of the content div. I have a margin-bottom on the project list div (the div all the thumbnails are in), but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style of paragraph at the end of the div to clear: both; or you can add a  to end of the div, and in your stylesheet set .clear{ clear: both;}

http://jsfiddle.net/rsoneill21/4YuhU/1/